# macOS - VisualEffectView appears broken when window is moved

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder, uivisualeffectview

I have built a macOS application which presents a window with a visual effect view as background view modally. When I move that presented window, the majority of the blurred area of the visual effect view becomes updated in real time. However, the lower part of the effect view doesn't become as often updated as the rest of the view, resulting in part of the effect view, that looks odd and doesn't seem quite right. I have appended some images to visualize those problems.

The first image shows how the lower part of the window looks like, when it is initially presented. The second image shows how the lower part looks like, when I move the window quite a bit down. You can see, that the blur effect appears to be broken. I had to shoot the second image with my cell phone's camera, because neither the builtin screen capture app nor the screen recorder function of QuickTime could capture/record that behavior.

How can I fix this odd behavior of the effect view?

Thanks in advance, Fabian.

[image: Initial window]
***Initial window state***

[image: Window after I moved it down on the screen]
***Effect view after I moved the window down on the screen***

---

**EDIT:**

How the visual effect view is implemented:
I use an Tab View Controller, which has a visual effect view added to it via the interface builder (Screenshot 1). In each of the content view controllers I have added an visual effect view to the view controller's view and put all the elements inside the effect view's content view (Screenshot 2).

[image: Tab view controller structure]
***Tab view controller structure***

[image: Content view controller structure]
***Content view controller structure***

Comment: I edited my question. You can see now the structure of my view setup in the interface builder.